# Is there any possible way to speed up the Android Emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator, qemu

I'm using a Windows 10 machine with Intel Core 2.20 GHz processor (x64-based processor) and 8.00 GB of RAM and I've assigned 2048 Mb of RAM to the emulator.

So, in my understanding the machine is not that bad to run the emulator quickly. But, emulator response time is too long and also utilizing `80% of CPU`, `95% of Memory` and `100% of Disk`.

Also, tried to assign less RAM from AVD manager to the same emulator but still the same issue and sometimes only white screen is appearing on the android emulator. I have android studio 2.3.3 and already tried to enable/disable the "Instant Run" from the settings but no success at all.

So, is there any possible way to fix this issue, or at least want to know why **speed/performance** of an android emulator is too slow instead of some external emulator such as `Genymotion`.

I've spent days on internet and on stack overflow but couldn't find a similar issue/solution and didn't understand the reason of slow performance of android emulator.

Comment: Without knowing the configuration of your emulator, it will be difficult for anyone to help you. For example, if you chose an `arm` emulator image, that will be slow.

Comment: There is a lot more to the emulator than RAM assignment.

Comment: Are you using the x86 version of the image?
Are you using hardware or software rendering?
Is HAXM activated when running the emulator?

Comment: I'm using `x86` image version along with `Multi-Core CPU 2 Enabled`, and VM heap is `256 MB`
and yes HAXM is also activated while executing the emulator

Comment: Also tried to enable/disable the `Hyper-V` option from the `Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off`, but no success at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Nox Player App* and use it like hardware device. You will be able to debug your code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I want to know why the speed of android emulator is so slow and on the same machine Genymotion is smooth and quick.